# How can I create a completely invisible button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a WPF button, that is completely invisible, but still has an onclick or click event, without resorting to something like MouseDown and check the keyeventargs, etc.

I have tried setting the button's visibility to Collapsed or Hidden, which also makes the button unclickable, and therefore useless for my purposes.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
<Button Opacity="0" />
```

Comment: Note that the button won't receive a Click event if its contents have manipulations enabled. But you can use a [StylusSystemGesture](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27272024/603828) event instead.

Answer (score 2):

just make a button and set

```
  button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

or

```
  button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: And you can click those? It seems...unlikely.

Comment: why not? just because they're not visible doesn't mean they're not clickable

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548490/how-to-make-an-invisible-button-to-run-a-command