# Create invisible clickable button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button

I've tried to create an invisible clickable button, but when I click it, nothing happens...

The code I used to make the button invisible:

```
button1.Visible = false;
```

I want to show a picture when the button is clicked (after it's been made invisible)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a completely invisible button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423947/how-can-i-create-a-completely-invisible-button)

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf or other?

Comment: You could use onMouse click on the form and check for x,y range

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead of `Invisible` property:

```
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = BackColor;
button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = BackColor;
button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = BackColor;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 private void CreateButton()
    {
        button1 = new Button();
        button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        button1.ForeColor = BackColor;
        button1.Location = new Point(197, 226); //Give your own location as needed
        button1.Name = "button1";
        button1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
        button1.TabIndex = 0;
        button1.Text = "button1";
        button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        button1.Click += this.button1_Click;
        Controls.Add(button1);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("clicked");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Begin by dragging in a brand new button from the toolbox. Going off the property list instead of doing it manually through code, changing the following settings should get you the desired result.

```
| Property                          | Settings    |
---------------------------------------------------
| BackColor                         | Transparent |
| FlatStyle                         | Flat        |
| FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor | Transparent |
| FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor | Transparent |
| ForeColor                         | Transparent |
| UseVisualStyleBackColor           | False       |
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that worked for me is I just hid it behind another control.

To do this in the Form Designer:

1. Put the button you want to hide anywhere on your form (over a larger, multiline textbox works well).
2. Right-click the button.
3. Click the option for "Send to Back."

Answer (score 0):

can be simple like that

```
button1.Opacity = 0;
```

For more security, add something like this

```
button1.IsEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Text = "&t"; // Ampersand followed by a letter
button1.Size = new Size(0, 0); 
button1.UseMnemonic = true;
```

Now the button is invisible and can be activated by pressing Alt + T

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but sadly doesn't directly answer the question as the poster was looking for a _clickable_ button, not one activated by a keyboard shortcut.