# How can I make an invisible clickable button in WinForms with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an invisible clickable button in WinForms but I can't figure out how to do it. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469265/create-invisible-clickable-button) post, but it wasn't much help because `Color.Transparent` isn't supported for the border color of buttons. Right now I have the following code:

```
StartGameButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
StartGameButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

The button `FlatStyle` is set to `Flat` through the Properties tab in the designer, and the `BackColor` is set to `Color.Transparent` the only thing I can see now is the border of the button, which is black.

I tried all the answers for the StackOverflow post I linked, but none of them helped. They all compiled and didn't hide the border, because they either forgot to add anything to hide the border or it didn't compile saying that `Color.Transparent` isn't supported for border colors, or they would try to use the `BackColor` and it for some reason compiled but still didn't hide the border.
I have also tried `StartGameButton.Visible = false;`, but then it makes the button unclickable for some reason.

Comment: You don't need a button. Handle click event of the container and check the coordinates to see if it's inside the desired rectangle (hypothetical button). Or add a transparent PictureBox to the container, and handle the Click event of the PictureBox.

Comment: Yeah that worked, I never would have thought to make a button out of something that's not a button, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    Button invisibleButton = new Button();
    invisibleButton.Size = new Size(100, 50); // Set the size of the button
    invisibleButton.Location = new Point(50, 50); // Set the location of the button
    invisibleButton.BackColor = Color.Transparent; // Make the button invisible
    invisibleButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent; // Make the button invisible when the mouse is over it
    invisibleButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent; // Make the button invisible when it's clicked
    invisibleButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; // Required to make the button invisible
    invisibleButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0; // Required to make the button invisible
    
    // Add a click event handler
    invisibleButton.Click += new EventHandler(InvisibleButton_Click);
    
    // Add the button to the form
    this.Controls.Add(invisibleButton);
    
    // The click event handler
    void InvisibleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invisible button clicked!");
    }
```

This code creates a button that is invisible but still clickable. The button's BackColor is set to Color.Transparent to make it invisible, and the FlatStyle property is set to FlatStyle.Flat to remove the 3D border effect. The FlatAppearance.BorderSize is set to 0 to remove the border. The FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor and FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor properties are also set to Color.Transparent to keep the button invisible when the mouse is over it and when it's clicked.

The Click event is handled by the InvisibleButton_Click method, which shows a message box when the button is clicked. The button is then added to the form's controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the button's background color the same as the current panel or form's background color, and you can prevent the button from being noticed with the codes below.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("...");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = button1.BackColor;
        button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    }
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aw9v.png)